# SynchronousQueue - Tasks getting rejected while max pool size has not been reached

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a piece of code that is meant to execute tasks (1000+). I have a core pool size of 10 and a max size of 100. I am using a SyncQ and so there is no queue size.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,100, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, queue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

This runs fine for about 1000 requests after which I started getting TaskRejectedException. The exception stack trace is something like the below-

```
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@56672127[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 20, queue tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 13431]] did not accept task: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1@462b281
```

I am trying to debug the problem and get it fixed.

What I expected to happen was:

1. ThreadPoolExecutor has 10 threads to accept requests.
2. When more than 10 tasks come in and previous 10 are not done yet, then new threads would be created until 100 (max pool size) is reached
3. When 100 tasks are running, the 101st task would be sent to the main thread (CallerRunsPolicy) and blocks the other requests until space is available for them to run.

What is happening (as per logs):

1. ThreadPoolExecutor starts with 10 threads and goes up to 20 (not the max?)
2. Queue size shows as 1000 when SyncQ does not have any capacity to store tasks
3. Tasks get rejected whenever we have >1000 requests to process.

The completed task count is not from a single run, it accrues over time because several others test at other times and not at the time of my testing.

I do not understand why the pool size stops at 20, queue size shows up as 1000 (instead of 0) and why tasks are getting rejected while we have syncQ with callersRunPolicy. Anyone knows what is going wrong with the SyncQ or the ThreadPoolExecutor?

I do have the option to remove SyncQ and add a bounded queue if that is the issue, but at this point I am not sure what is causing the issue as I see queue size being printed for a syncQ.

Comment: Queue size shows as 1000....err where exactly? `SynchronousQueue` has no size.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, I understand it has no size, but the exception shows it as `queue tasks: 1000`, which I assume is of the queue I am using in the pool? Which is a syncQ, I expected it be 0.

Comment: That's what happens when you assume things. `SynchronousQueue.size()` returns a constant `0`, so it definitely isn't the queue (or fill) size.

Comment: @Kayaman you are correct, it does, which is what is part of my question, why does the exception state the queue size is 1000? Shouldn't it say 0, issues with pool sizes might not be related to the syncQ at all, but the queue size showing up as 1000 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because the exception isn't referring to the queue you think it is. There aren't many options for impossible results. My next suggestion will be a cursed JVM running on Indian burial ground.

Comment: I would make sure I'm looking at the correct pool. If you're configuring it completely different than it's acting, then it doesn't seem like they're the same pool.